# Trimming whitespace in Array

Tags: arrays, rust, whitespace, trim

I have been trying to trim whitespaces in my long array which consists of almost all the periodic table elements but not able to find the function that does that, I did read the documentation on [trim](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) but found out that none of them work with the array.

Here is my long array

```
let mut elements = ["Please start with 1"," Hydrogen"," Helium","Lithium"," Beryllium","Boron","Carbon"," Nitrogen","Oxygen","Fluorine","Neon","Sodium","Magnesium","Aluminium","Silicon","Phosphorus","Sulfur"," Chlorine","Argon","Potassium","Calcium "," Scandium","Titanium","Vanadium",
                "Chromium","Manganese"," Iron","Cobalt","Nickel","Copper","Zinc","Gallium","Germanium","Arsenic"," Selenium","Bromine","Krypton","Rubidium","Strontium","  Yttrium","Zirconium ","Niobium ","Molybdenum ","Technetium ","Ruthenium ","Rhodium","Palladium","Silver",
                "Cadmium "," Indium ","Tin","Antimony"," Tellurium","Iodine","Xenon","Cesium","Barium","Lanthanum","Cerium"," Praseodymium","Neodymium"," Promethium "," Samarium ","Europium "," Gadolinium","Terbium "," Dysprosium ","Holmium "," Erbium","Thulium","Ytterbium","Lutetium","Hafnium",
                "Tantalum "," Tungsten","Rhenium ","Osmium ","Iridium ","Platinum","Gold","Mercury"," Thallium","Lead ","Bismuth"," Polonium" ,"Astatine","Radon ","Francium ","Radium"," Actinium","Thorium"," Protactinium","Uranium","Neptunium","Plutonium","Americium","Curium","Berkelium","Californium"];
```

Now in a few elements there are whitespaces that ruin the output.

Is there any way you can trim the whitespaces in an array?

Comment: A good question on StackOverflow needs to include a [mcve] that shows what you have tried. Take a look at the [help] to learn more.

Comment: @Herohtar I will edit my question today, I have understood it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map) with `trim` as:

```rust
let trimmed = elements.map(str::trim);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e0d45028f0b8416d4f9df1e1ef666d19)

Notice that this builds a new array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without building a new array by modifying each element in place.

```
for word in elements.iter_mut() {
    *word = word.trim();
}
```

Or using iterators

```
elements.iter_mut().for_each(|word| *word = word.trim());
```